# Backbone and Rails Fetching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

So I am pulling in a model with model.fetch

That model has a collection.  The json contains an array (of stops).
The collection in the model is being overridden by the array since that is what the json returned by model.fetch contains.  Is there any way around this?

```
App.Models.Itinerary = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '',
    ID: "",
    Name: "",
    stops: new App.Collections.StopCollection(),
```

Then I call window.Itinerary.fetch()

and stops is now an array (with the correct data)

JSON I get back is

(model)

```
{"ID":"7cd9dcdc-54f1-4704-a8be-393d67559b7e","Name":"China","stops":
```

(collection)

```
    [{"ID":"1","Name":"Jordan Stop","Notes":"Ayo Notes!","OrderNumber":null},
{"ID":"5","Name":"Another Jordan Stop","Notes":"Aya Notes :-!","OrderNumber":null}]}
```

Comment: What does your controller method look like in Rails?

Comment: @BrendanBenson
`def show
    itinerary = Itinerary.find(params[:id])
    render json: itinerary
  end`

which uses the as_json from Itinerary.rb


  `def as_json(option={})
    super({ID: self.ID, Name: self.Name, include: [:stops]})
  end`

Comment: I mean my json is coming back as it should I guess?  Just backbone.js is like hey it's an array and overwrites the attribute stops (of type StopCollection()) with an array.